# Troubles understanding a django 2fa authentication library

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add `2fa` to my `Django` project, so I decided to adopt [this library](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth).

To understand how it works, I'm following their [example](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/tree/master/example). My idea would be to "**merge**" my current work, so that I can have both what I already have and what the example gives.

Now I'm trying to edit the *example*'s **login** form, but I can't find it.
Normally, in `django`, I expect a **login** form to be defined in a **views.py** file, and it looks something like that:

```
         if form.is_valid():
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)


                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {username}")
                    return redirect("main:homepage")
                else:
                    messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password")
```

But I can't find anything that looks like this on the **example** folder. Can anyone give me some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally in Django I'd expect most projects to be [using the batteries-included `LoginView`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/632d4861ddb99a2c9d11642fcfa4ad542b427d6b/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L38) or deriving from it instead of rolling one's own as in your example. (In fact, even your example looks like it's a function view – you'd get by with far less code by just deriving from a `FormView` if you did need to roll your own login view.)

In fact, that's more or less what's happening in the example project too.

You can see [here in `urls.py`](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/blob/268c0d64b1aa912038e5c96ea688fbec17663a34/example/urls.py#L39) that all of `two_factor.urls` is included, which includes, among others, [a login view](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/blob/268c0d64b1aa912038e5c96ea688fbec17663a34/two_factor/urls.py#L11), which is defined [over here](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/blob/268c0d64b1aa912038e5c96ea688fbec17663a34/two_factor/views/core.py#L51).

(It doesn't, actually, derive from Django's login view, but the idea is the same.)

Comment: I understood! Thank you!